# QUERY Data from an external sheet with conditions on data from both sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I kind of need your help on this.
I have 2 separate spreadsheets:

**Spreadsheet A:**

```
ColA   ColB
AA1    Want1
AA2    Want2
AA3    Want3
```

**Spreadsheet B:**

```
ColC   ColD
AA3    <Display Correctly In Here>
AA1    ...
AA2    ...
```

I tried using the following formula (because I need them to fill automatically):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("LinkOfSheetA", "SheetA!A2:B"), 
"Select Col2 WHERE Col1=C")
```

I figured that either I cannot do it this way or that I do not know how to point back to ColC in SheetB. Really need your help, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(C2:C25,IMPORTRANGE("LinkOfSheetA", "SheetA!A2:B"),2,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is, in Spreadsheet B D2 and copied down to suit, something like:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(" k e y ","SheetA!A2:B10"),"select Col2 WHERE Col1='"&C2&"' ")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually found that i forgot to put the ' before " after Col1.

Comment: Here's the final formula:
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(" k e y ","SheetA!A2:B10"),"select Col2 WHERE Col1='"&C2&"' ")

The thing is that... the information only appears in the first row.
The 2nd, 3rd rows are blank.

The formula pulls all the data in the column if I remove the WHERE part.